# SQL Syntax Error - Multiple Count Multiple Criteria - MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

First question...

I've been researching this site and found a SQL that should help me...but I'm getting an error that I can't solve. Find below SQL and Error:

```
SELECT field1,
   Sum(IIf(status = "Accepted", 1, 0)) AS [field1_Accepted]
   Sum(IIf(status = "Rejected", 1, 0)) AS [field1_Rejected]
   Sum(IIf(status = "Cancelled", 1, 0)) AS [field1_Cancelled]
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY field1;
```

Error: The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect. (Error 3141)

My expectations from this query is this one:

```
field1/accepted/rejected/cancelled
a/1/2/3
b/2/3/5
c/2/3/4
```

Letters should be my fld1 names and the other numbers should be a count on how much field has accepted,rejected and cancelled status...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expressions in the `SELECT` statement need to be separated by commas. You are missing commas between the column expressions:

```
SELECT field1,
   Sum(IIf(status = "Accepted", 1, 0)) AS [field1_Accepted], -- <<== Here
   Sum(IIf(status = "Rejected", 1, 0)) AS [field1_Rejected], -- <<== Here
   Sum(IIf(status = "Cancelled", 1, 0)) AS [field1_Cancelled]
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY field1;
```